# With `su <name> --login`, what's the alternative to --login?

Tags: bash, shell, login, su

The [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/su.html) for `su` states that for `su <name> --login`, adding the `--login` makes it a login shell. What's the alternative to this? I assumed that since you're changing the user, you have to log in, so you'd automatically be executing a login shell.

Comment: Small inaccuracy: although at least some implementations of `su` recognize `--login` as an equivalent to `-l`, the man page you linked to seems not to mention it at all. Consider [edit]ing and linking to a man page that actually states about `--login`.

Answer (score 1):

You may or may not specify `--login`, `-l` or `-`. Try it both ways and you will [discover](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26782/108618) that `su` allows you to spawn a login or non-login shell.

It's not we call the first shell spawned for a user "login shell" by definition. Login shell is a shell started somewhat differently, so it knows it should [behave differently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/108618). And there is no mechanism to force the first shell to be a login shell. When you read (in the linked answer):

> A login shell is the first process that executes under your user ID when you log in for an interactive session

then remember it doesn't have to be this way. It is only because

> The login process tells the shell to behave as a login shell

but in general it may not. It was designed/configured to do this because it makes most sense.

The concept of login shell allows one shell set up the environment (and possibly other things, whatever they can be) for itself and for all its descendants. A shell among the descendants doesn't have to do this again, it inherits. In some cases it might do this again, in some cases it shouldn't, in some cases it mustn't.

There's nothing fundamentally wrong or unsafe in spawning a non-login shell without spawning a login shell first. It's all about whether or not a login shell is needed.

- If a user comes "from the outside" then skipping what login shell does will result in running his or her processes with possibly basic environment. This is not particularly useful for the user. Login shells address exactly this issue.
- There are scenarios when the environment is left basic or is set up by a process other than a shell. All descendant shells (if any) may be non-login. In such case there is no login-shell at all.
- If an already logged in user uses `su bob`, there's presumably a useful environment and `su` inherits it. Now there are two possibilities:

  - The user may want things to work as if `bob` logged in anew ("from the outside"). `su --login bob` is the way. Note `su --login` not only spawns a login shell; it prepares a fresh minimal environment first, so there are no leftovers from the invoking user's environment.
  - The user may want to work in a shell as another user while keeping the old environment. It may be that keeping the environment is crucial. This is when `--login` should not be used.

And to make clear:

> I assumed that since you're changing the user, you have to log in, so you'd automatically be executing a login shell.

The assumption is wrong. There is no "have to", there is no "automatically". With `su` you decide if you want a login or non-login shell, then invoke accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> since you're changing the user, you have to log in

Technically, no, you don't. As with many other things on Linux, "logging in" is not actually a single operation – it consists of several separate steps, some of which can be skipped or reconfigured. Authentication, authorization, session setup, and the actual UID change.

For example, a privileged process can always just change its current process credentials (UID, GID, group list) by calling setreuid() or similar functions, without having to do anything else.

(Though programs *should* call PAM's "session setup" phase at least, so that it would load environment through pam_env, set resource limits via pam_limit, register with logind through pam_systemd...)

> you have to log in, so you'd automatically be executing a login shell.

Those things are unrelated to each other.

- Logging in a user doesn't require executing *anything,* not even a shell. For example, graphical desktop environments will log you in without really running your "login shell", as will FTP or SFTP connections.
- A "login" shell only differs from a non-login shell in that it's being told to load a different initialization script, mostly. For example, bash will read ~/.bash_profile only if it's run in "login shell" mode.